# SQL error Importing Excel data into Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm importing excel in access using vba, and I'm having the following error. I believe the error is in sql, would it have to do with the way I declared the name of the columns?

base has 31 columns

Put all the columns as a string in the base in access, just the dates that don't, just to test if that was the error

Could anyone tell me what the error was?

```
Code:

Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim MDB  As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim FD   As ADODB.Field
Dim SQL   As String



Dim W  As Worksheet



Dim UltCel As Range



Dim Ln As Long
Dim Col As Integer





 Set W = Sheets("Plan1")
 Ln = 2
 Col = 1
 W.Select
 W.Range("A1").Select

 MDB.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\DatabasePerfildePerda.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

 Set UltCel = W.Cells(W.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)



 Do While Ln <= UltCel.Row

 SQL = "INSERT INTO tbdados3"
 SQL = SQL & "(Mes por Extenso, Secao Industrial, Tipo, by-pass, Sigla, Motivo, Classificacao, Responsavel pela Solucao, Area, Causa Raiz, Turno, Data Inicio, Hora Inicio, Data Fim, Hora Fim, Tempo, Taxa Alimetacao, Reducao Alimentacao, TAG, Componente, Ponto de Causa, Observacoes, Usuario, Unidade, Familia, Ano, Mês, Ano Mes, Dia, Inicio da ocorrencia, Final da Ocorrencia, Frequencia de Falha)"
 SQL = SQL & "values"
 SQL = SQL & "('" & W.Cells(Ln, Col).Value & "', "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 1).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 2).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 3).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 4).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 5).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 6).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 7).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 8).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 9).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 10).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 11).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 12).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 13).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 14).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 15).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 16).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 17).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 18).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 19).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 20).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 21).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 22).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 23).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 24).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 25).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 26).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 27).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 28).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 29).Value & "' , "
 SQL = SQL & "'" & W.Cells(Ln, Col + 30).Value & "' ) "


RS.Open SQL, MDB



Ln = Ln + 1
Col = 1
Application.StatusBar = Ln
DoEvents

 Loop

 MDB.Close







Set W = Nothing
Set MDB = Nothing
Set RS = Nothing
Set FD = Nothing
Set UltCel = Nothing



MsgBox "Processo Concluido"








End Sub
```

Comment: You need to know what the format for the field corresponding to the date in your database is. If the format is a date, you need to know what date format it is.
Since the date of Excel data can be imported if it is not a character, it seems that you need to change the format of the original data and the date of Excel to the date format of the original data, and then insert the command.

Comment: Don't you need to put square brackets around the column names with spaces in them .. like [Mes por Extenso] for Access to know that it is a column name with spaces in it?
Also you can't ask Stackoverflow what the error is, you need to post the error you're getting? For instance the RS (RecordSet?) object in your VBA code is not set to anything in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you deal with data in SQL within Access, the rule of thumb is that any text data gets wrapped in single quotes, any date data gets wrapped in hashes, and numeric data does not need wrapping in anything. You may want to put a `Debug.Print SQL` in your code after you have built it to see in the immediate window what you are trying to execute.

Also, having field names with spaces in causes problems, so you should either rename the fields without spaces, or else wrap the field names in square brackets.

Possibly a better option is to link to the Excel file (using TransferSpreadsheet) and then insert the data into your table:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tblTemp", "J:\Downloads\test.xlsx", True
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table3 ( F1, F2, F3 ) " _
    & " SELECT Customer, Product, Order " _
    & " FROM tblTemp;"
```

You will need to delete the previous linked table if you are running this multiple times.

Regards,